# Conditionally deleting rows does not work as intended in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.4

I have a dataframe which has a sample column containing duplicate samples (ending with _2) and a same column detailing which one is the original sample. The New Category contains a mutation type where Pathogenic/Likely Pathogenic is the most damaging while Likely Benign is the least damaging. Below demonstrates a reduced/basic version of my dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Sample', 'same','New Category'],
             data=[
                   ['HG_12_34', 'HG_12_34', 'Pathogenic/Likely Pathogenic'],
                   ['HG_12_34_2', 'HG_12_34', 'Likely Benign'],
                   ['KD_89_9', 'KD_89_9', 'Likely Benign'],
                   ['KD_98_9_2', 'KD_89_9', 'Likely Benign'],
                   ['LG_3_45', 'LG_3_45', 'Likely Benign'],
                   ['LG_3_45_2', 'LG_3_45', 'VUS']
                   ])
```

I want to conditionally delete either a sample or its duplicate depending upon which one has the least damaging mutation in the New Category i.e. if one sample has Likely Benign and the duplicate has a Pathogenic/Likley Pathogenic variant then I want to remove/delete the sample row.

I have attempted this by passing the dataframe to a function which returns a list of indexes that represent the rows to be deleted and I have subsequently dropped them.

```
def get_unwanted_duplicates_ix(df):

    # filter df for samples that have a duplicate
    same_only = df.groupby("same").filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)

    list_index_to_delete = []


    for num in range(0,same_only.shape[0]-1):

        row1 = same_only.irow(num)
        row2 = same_only.irow(num+1)
        index = list(same_only.index.values)[num]



        if row1['Sample']+"_2" == row2['Sample'] or \
           row1['Sample'] == row2['Sample']+"_2":

            if row1['New Category'] == row2['New Category']:
                list_index_to_delete.append(index+1)

            elif row1['New Category']  == "Pathogenic/Likely Pathogenic"  \
               and row2['New Category']  != "Pathogenic/Likely Pathogenic":
                list_index_to_delete.append(index+1)

            elif row2['New Category']  == "Pathogenic/Likely Pathogenic"  \
               and row1['New Category']  != "Pathogenic/Likely Pathogenic":
                list_index_to_delete.append(index)

            elif row1['New Category']  == "VUS"  \
               and row2['New Category']  != "VUS":
                list_index_to_delete.append(index+1)

            elif row2['New Category']  == "VUS"  \
               and row1['New Category']  != "VUS":
                list_index_to_delete.append(index)

            elif row1['New Category'] == 'Likely Benign' \
              and row2['New Category'] == 'Likely Benign':
                list_index_to_delete.append(index+1)

            else:
                list_index_to_delete.append(index+1)

    return list_index_to_delete

unwanted = get_unwanted_duplicates_ix(df)
df = df.drop(df.index[unwanted])
```

The above function is a mess and, unsurprisingly, does not function as I had hoped. A point in the right direction would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, replace mutation severity with integers (higher values mean more damaging).

```
df['New Category code'] = df['New Category'].replace(
    {'Likely Benign': 1, 'VUS': 2, 'Pathogenic/Likely Pathogenic': 3})
```

The next command depends on whether you want to keep multiple rows with the same severity. If yes, then group by `same` column and select the rows with the max severity code:

```
df[df.groupby('same')['New Category code'].transform(max) == df['New Category code']]                   

      Sample      same                  New Category  New Category code
0   HG_12_34  HG_12_34  Pathogenic/Likely Pathogenic                  3
2    KD_89_9   KD_89_9                 Likely Benign                  1
3  KD_98_9_2   KD_89_9                 Likely Benign                  1
5  LG_3_45_2   LG_3_45                           VUS                  2
```

If no (always keep only one row in each group), then instead sort values ascending by the severity and take the last row in each group (thanks @JonClements for the idea):

```
df.sort_values('New Category code').groupby('same').last()

             Sample                  New Category  New Category code
same                                                                
HG_12_34   HG_12_34  Pathogenic/Likely Pathogenic                  3
KD_89_9   KD_98_9_2                 Likely Benign                  1
LG_3_45   LG_3_45_2                           VUS                  2
```

Comment: Is that what you want, or you want to group not by `same` column? If not, please add the desired output to the question.

Comment: I'd suggest that instead of transforming and comparing the max values (which for groups with more than one max value will return multiple samples), sort by your new category code descending, then apply `groupby('same').first()` instead... (or sort ascending then apply `.last()` - whichever you fancy)